# Proper way to convert custom class to List

Tags: c#, json

I am grabbing a json from a 3rd party API and I'm working on building a report system for the API.  I have been taking the json, **deserializing** it, turning it into a **list**, then putting in an sqlite db to manipulate.  I've done this with 6 or 7 different json objects, and it's worked just fine, but this last one has list within a list and i'm having difficulties doing the conversion.  *I am relatively new to json objects* so i apologize if this have been answered, but i'm looking for 2 days trying to find an answer, with no luck.

the json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 99040,
        "machine": 41855,
        "tooling": null,
        "eventschedule": 94239,
        "open": true,
        "created": "2020-04-23T10:51:41.007",
        "createdby": "fistname.lastname",
        "lastlaunched": "2020-04-23T10:54:03.519",
        "lastcompleted": null,
        "launch": "2020-04-25T23:59:00",
        "due": "2020-04-30T23:59:00",
        "scheduled": "2020-04-27T07:00:00",
        "occurrencecount": 1,
        "launchprior": 604740,
        "scheduleprior": 320340,
        "lastupdated": "2020-04-23T14:55:02.592",
        "lastupdatedby": "fistname.lastname",
        "lastcyclecompleted": 0,
        "suspended": false,
        "suspendedon": null,
        "suspendedby": null,
        "machine_code": "AC700B5",
        "line_code": "FCLT-HVAC",
        "line_abbreviation": "FCLT-HVAC",
        "dispatch_type_code": "PM",
        "occurrence_type": "Weekly",
        "next_occurrence": {
            "machine": {
                "created": "2020-04-13T16:07:47.213",
                "lastupdated": "2020-04-13T16:07:47.213",
                "id": 41855
            },
            "launch": "2020-05-02T23:59:00",
            "scheduled": "2020-05-04T07:00:00",
            "due": "2020-05-07T23:59:00",
            "id": 217290
        },
        "estimated_hours": 2.5
    }
}
```

the c# class:

```
    public class Machine
    {
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastupdated { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }

    }

    public class NextOccurrence
    {
        public Machine machine { get; set; }
        public DateTime launch { get; set; }
        public DateTime scheduled { get; set; }
        public DateTime due { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int machine { get; set; }
        public object tooling { get; set; }
        public int eventschedule { get; set; }
        public bool open { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public string createdby { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastlaunched { get; set; }
        public object lastcompleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime launch { get; set; }
        public DateTime due { get; set; }
        public DateTime scheduled { get; set; }
        public int occurrencecount { get; set; }
        public int launchprior { get; set; }
        public int scheduleprior { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastupdated { get; set; }
        public string lastupdatedby { get; set; }
        public int lastcyclecompleted { get; set; }
        public bool suspended { get; set; }
        public object suspendedon { get; set; }
        public object suspendedby { get; set; }
        public string machine_code { get; set; }
        public string line_code { get; set; }
        public string line_abbreviation { get; set; }
        public string dispatch_type_code { get; set; }
        public string occurrence_type { get; set; }
        //public NextOccurrence next_occurrence { get; set; }
        public double estimated_hours { get; set; }

    }

    public class Root
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }

    }
```

C# task

```
 public async Task<String> makeRequestAsyncGetMachineScheduleInfo(string eventschedulemachine)
    {

        var jsonResult = new Root();
        List<Data> schList = new List<Data>();
        
            var responseStringGET = await client.GetStringAsync("example.com")
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
            jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseStringGET);
            schList=jsonResult.data;

        
        List<object> jsomParams = (schList as IEnumerable<object>).Cast<object>().ToList();
        SqliteDataAccess.Save(jsomParams, "Schedule List", typeof(Data));
        return "success";
    }
```

The error happens at `schList=jsonResult.data` within the task which is :

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Tools.RestClient.Data' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Tools.RestClient.Data>'

If i change the the Data class to `List<Data>`, i lose the above error, but then get the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
> current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[L2L_Tools.RestClient+Data]' because
> the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly.

Comment: Do not change class, change the `schList=jsonResult.data` to `schList.Add(jsonResult.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change method to this. Its should work:

```
public async Task < String > makeRequestAsyncGetMachineScheduleInfo(string eventschedulemachine)
{
 var jsonResult = new Root();
 List<Data> schList = new List<Data>();

 var responseStringGET = await client.GetStringAsync("example.com").ConfigureAwait(false);
 jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseStringGET);
 List<Data> schList = new List<Data>();
 schList.Add(jsonResult.data);

 SqliteDataAccess.Save(schList, "Schedule List", typeof(List<Data>));
 return "success";
}
```

Comment: FFS. I've been staring at that code for 2 days. Thanks imam